# Using GSON to parse mixed type fields?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How can I use GSON with mixed type fields, is it possible?

```
{
  'field': false
}

// or

{
  'field': [
    1,2,3,4
  ]
}
```

My GSON class:

```
public class MyModel {

    public  HashMap<ArrayList,Boolean>  blockedusers;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you have to handle if the json is an array or a primitive type. try code below:

```
String case1 = "{'field':false}";
String case2 = "{'field':[1,2,3,4]}";
JsonElement jsonElement = ((JsonObject)(new JsonParser().parse(case1))).get("field");

if(jsonElement instanceof JsonArray) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray)jsonElement;
    if(jsonArray != null && jsonArray.size() > 0) {
        for (JsonElement aJsonElement : jsonArray) {
            // TODO: handle json element inside array 
            System.out.println(aJsonElement);
        }
    }
} else if (jsonElement instanceof JsonPrimitive) {
    boolean value = jsonElement.getAsBoolean();
    System.out.println("value:" + value);
}
```

Also you can write a custom `TypeAdapter`. See [my answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804952/how-to-config-gson-to-exclude-0-integer-values/25947499#25947499).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [GSON parsing unspecified type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164515/gson-parsing-unspecified-type-variable?rq=1)

I think you have to define a custom deserializer:

```java
        public class MyJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<YourParsedData> {

       @Override 
       public YourParsedData deserialize(final JsonElement je, final Type type, final JsonDeserialization Context jdc) throws JsonParseException
       {
          final JsonObject obj = je.getAsJsonObject(); //our original full json string
          final JsonElement serviceElement = obj.get("field");


         //here we provide the functionality to handle the naughty element. It seems emtpy string is returned as a JsonPrimitive... so one option
         if(serviceElement instanceOf JsonPrimitive)
         {
//get Boolean
         }

         return YourParsedData.create(); //provide the functionality to take in the parsed data
       }
     }
```

you can use it with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(ServiceState.class, new ServiceDeserializer())
    .create();
```